# Is there a fast iterator over random numbers in python?

Tags: python, performance, random, python-3.x, iterator

I'm using a lot of random numbers in a python script of mine. Traditionally I simply called random.random() where I needed them, but now that makes up a significant fraction of the execution time. So I'd like to increase the speed.

The original version could be boiled down to this:

```
from random import random
for _ in range(cycles):
    _ = random()
```

Notice that there is a fixed (of course more complicated) iteration going on.

Now I tried using `numpy`:

```
from numpy.random import random
for _ in range(cycles):
    _ = random()
```

On the one hand this is even slower than the build-in random, but on the other hand numpy.random.random supports generating a bulk set of random numbers:

```
from numpy.random import random
rnd = random(cycles)
i = 0
for _ in range(cycles):
    _ = rnd[i]
    i += 1
```

Great! This only has about a **fifth** of the original running time.

The problem I have is, that it is not very nice to maintain the separate index `i`, so I would rather like to write something like this:

```
from numpy.random import random
from numpy import nditer
iter_rnd = nditer(random(cycles))
for _ in range(cycles):
    _ = next(iter_rnd)
```

Unfortunately this is just as slow as the first two versions. Generator expression and function are even worse. So is there something more elegant and still fast?

Comment: The best speedup (up to 1000x) will come from replacing iteration with numpy vectorized operations. If you can do that, do it. If you post more detail about what you're doing with the numbers, we may be able to help you do that.

Comment: In the meantime, have you tried just [enumerating](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the array?

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for the suggestions. Doing vectorized operations is really an intriguing idea. But that would require a major rebuilding of the algorithm. I'll definitely think about it.

Comment: @user2357112: Using enumerate is slow again. It is really frustrating how such a simple thing can add so much (relative) overhead...

Comment: Just how little work are you doing in the loop body? Post the code; it's almost certainly short. We might be able to vectorize this right now.

Comment: Also, you might be using `enumerate` wrong. Your for loops are weird. I've posted an example of how to use it correctly.

Comment: @user2357112: it is definitely not short. There are several (at least six, depending on how you count) nested loops with reading and writing properties of various objects. The random numbers are needed in the inner most loop, which is executed up to several million times.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, random_number in enumerate(rnd):
    do_whatever(i, random_number)
```

[`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is the usual tool to use when you want to iterate over a sequence and its indices. If you're using numpy, though, it's generally better to avoid iteration as much as possible. Replacing iteration with numpy vectorized operations can make your code shorter, cleaner, and up to 1000 times faster.

While we're at it, I'd like to point out something strange I noticed in your use of `for` loops.

```
from numpy.random import random
rnd = random(cycles)
i = 0
for _ in range(cycles):
    _ = rnd[i]
    i += 1
```

You seem to use `for` loops as a way to repeat a body of code a certain number of times, completely ignoring the iteration variable. `for _ in range(cycles)` already iterates over the integers from `0` to `cycles - 1`; you don't need to manually increment a separate `i` variable. This code could have been simplified to the following:

```
from numpy.random import random
rnd = random(cycles)
for i in range(cycles):
    random_number = rnd[i]
```

Comment: You are of course correct, that the code can be simplified there. But I wanted to illustrate, that there is a fixed iteration (albeit much more complex and nested) going on, that is independent of the random numbers, just as in the initial example.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built-in way to iterate over the numpy array, rather than nditer()?

```
from numpy.random import random
rnd = iter(random(cycles))
for _ in range(cycles):
    _ = rnd.next()
```

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce the times you mention.  The examples using numpy are *all* slower than the built-in random module for me.